# SVG недостатки

Tags: svg

SVG, я с этим форматом особа не разбирался, только на уровне статьи из вики и небольших экспериментов. Мне интересно, почему обладая столькими достоинствами такими как: маштабируемость, открытость и т.д. он не получил большого распространения, ведь недостатки-то не настолько существенны чтобы его не применять.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём его недостатки и достоинства.

P.S.Мне это нужно по двум причинал: сдать лабу и понять что лучше мне использовать на своём сайте для анимаций(пока думаю, что svg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Причины, по которым SVG не получил до сих пор широкого распространения (хотя ситуация меняется с появлением HTML5), не связана с его техническими особенностями. Так получилось. Во-первых, сегментация рынка обозревателей препятствует одновременной поддержке разными производителями даже технологий, поддерживаемых стандартами W3C: синхронизация действий разных производителей занимает много времени. Во-вторых, у всех участников рынка существуют свои коммерческие интересы, и часто получается проще и выгоднее сделать что-то свое, чем поддерживать единый стандарт: как результат появляются технологии вроде Silverlight и Flash.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я сейчас взял одну и ту же картинку в разных форматах: svg, jpeg, png, gif. В сравнении svg ведёт себя довольно неплохо и учитывая, что на нём ещё и анимации можно делать и различные картографические приложения, то он вообще тогда всех обходит.

Comment: В данном случае (масштабирование) лучше ведёт себя любой векторный формат (по сравнению с расторовым). Из недостатков svg (по сравнению с тем же flash'ем) -- больший объем (xml вместо двоичного файла). Ну и самым главным сдерживающим фактором было, что msie клал на поддержку svg (а это немаленькое количество пользователей).

Comment: Что касаеться анимации в 99% случаев - достаточно html canvasa.

По поводу IE - одноклассники и VK, например, тоже кладут на поддержку старых IE (и я их, в этом, поддерживаю на 100%). Если разработка нетривиальна - ИМХО заморчиваться с кроссбраузерностью пустая трата времени (если речь именно о проекте - пока вы напишите, уже, глядишь народ на IE10 попереседает, ну вообщем вы поняли =))

Comment: Если кому интересно - я тестировал что лучше подходит для разработки браузерных игр (flash не рассматривался) и пришел к выводу что лучше всего для этих целей подходит старый добрый html + css3. SVG - сильно тяжелый + про поддержку тут уже писали. Кто-то скажет - так css3 поддерживеться еще хуже - да, это правда, в IE эти игры рботатьне будут, зато на всех моб.платформах на ура.
****
Ну и добавлю - лучшим решение оказалось в первую очередь в связи с легкостью преобразований(дописал стиль и все) ну и, конечно-же, скоростью генерирования страницы (нативные html парсеры очень быстрые у всех)

Comment: Большое спасибо за развёрнутые ответы, мне нужно-то для проекта, анимации ввиде движения точки по различным траекториям и смена фона при этом, думаю что html\canvas для этого оптимально подойдёт. 

п.с. Лабораторную сдал=))